# How to change the label in a LabeledPoint RDD

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd, key-value

I have a large amount of data as a LabeledPoint RDD assigned to seven different integer labels.

```
 [LabeledPoint(5.0,[2590.0,56.0,2.0,212.0,-6.0,390.0,220.0,235.0,151.0,6225.0]),
 LabeledPoint(2.0, [2804.0,139.0,9.0,268.0,65.0,3180.0,234.0,238.0,135.0,6121.0])....
```

I need to make this problem binary to pass through BoostedGradientTrees in MLLib, so I would like all features with label 2.0 to be a 1.0, and 0.0 otherwise. I'm new to working with RDDs and I can not for the life of me figure out how to change the label without running into an OutOfMemory error. I tried several different approaches and I figured something like this would be easiest:

```
def to_binary(Data):
    Datazero = Data.filter(lambda x: (x != 2.0, y))
    Data = Data.subtract(Datazero)
    Datazero = Datazero.map(lambda x:(0.0,y))
    Data = Data.map(lambda x: (1.0, y))
    Data = Datazero.union(Data)
    
    return Data
```

But obviously this returns an error as I don't know how to work with LabeledPoint objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to define an auxiliary function and to separately filter the two cases. The functional lambda environment supports an internal if-else environment:

```
Data = Data.map(lambda point : LabeledPoint(1, point.features) if point.label == 2.0 \
                         else LabeledPoint(0, point.features))
```